# Android Post request not posting any data on server

Tags: java, android, post, httpurlconnection

=====**Updated**========
Actually below code is fine, My problem is at server side.
=====**Updated**========

Below is my code,I am using `HttpURLConnection` but not able to send `JSON` data to server.

Please help me Thanks in advance

```
 JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("ID", "25")
    Log.e("test", jo.toString());

    url = new URL(URL);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    //Send request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
    connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(jo.toString());

    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    //Get Response
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int chr;
    while ((chr = is.read()) != -1) {
    sb.append((char) chr);
    }
    line = sb.toString();
    Log.e("json_temp", line);
    rd.close();
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so, post the stack trace as well.

Comment: No, I am not getting any exception.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: Have you tried to specify a "Content-Length” HTTP header?

Comment: @RohanKamat I want, if I print request on server than it should showing me  some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is fine**, it doesn't show a blank array, but a string "Array()". I tried a resource test, and that's exactly what it showed me.
If you type in the URL in the browser, you should see the same thing.
[image: Resource test]

Comment: Thankyou, But  please check response, you get empty array but in array there should be some data.

Comment: Once again, it's not an empty array, it's a string that says "Array()"

Comment: If you see the response content type, it's text/html not application/json

Comment: So you want to say that there is some problem at server side.

Comment: Perhaps, but since I don't know exactly what was expected, I can't say for sure... But most probably. Your code is definitely fine though, try some other url...

Comment: And? Try performing a resource test to make sure the output you get via code matches.

Comment: I found my problem.There is some problem at server side. Thank you very much Rohan